# MySQL query to get items within range of two datetimes while working with something greater than or equal to the begining of the range

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have two fields in my DB table a `start_time` and and `end_time` example:

```
start_time: 2013-04-20 13:07:00
end_time: 2013-04-20 12:07:00
```

my query currently contains

```
 where `start_time` >= '2013-04-20 14:13:20' AND `end_time` <= '2013-04-20 18:13:20'
```

which due to the way the query is the `start_time: 2013-04-20 13:07:00` will not pull in the result so I am seeking idea of how to compensate for that. The time thats generated for the pull already sets the time back an hour from the current time, and sets the end time to 4 hours from the current time.

Comment: How can something end an hour before it starts?

Comment: Are you using timestamps or datetimes?  They treat timezones differently, which may be the cause of your problems.

Comment: I am using datetime, and the timezone thing is a whole different problem I am also tackling in conjunction with this one. Working on converting existing code to use GMT while converting all datetime records to gmt equivalents so I can use offsets based on a persons location. As it stands most datetime records in the DB currently use eastern timezone references, while most of the users are in pacific timezone. Something the original plan didn't spec out when it was coded.. go figure, all in all trying to fix it all best I can

Answer (score -1):

don't use `>=` and `<=` in query
use some thing like this to fix it.
`where (start_time > '2013-04-20 14:13:20' or start_time = '2013-04-20 14:13:20' ) AND (end_time < '2013-04-20 18:13:20' or end_time = '2013-04-20 18:13:20')`